# Run multiple jmx files in Parallel

Tags: java, maven, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

We have project structure as src/test/jmeter/regressionTests/jmx1,jmx2,jmx2
The regressionTests folder has different jmx files. These files can execute in parallel.(They have no dependency on each other.Each jmx file creates its own data and then deletes the data created at last.)

Currently we run them using maven command :

```
-Pprofile-jmeter jmeter:jmeter -DtestType=regressionTest -DskipTests=true
```

The pom.xml config is as follow :

```
<profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>profile-jmeter</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.10.1</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>run-jmeter-tests</id>
                                <phase>verify</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>jmeter</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <testFilesDirectory>${basedir}/src/test/jmeter/scripts/${testType}</testFilesDirectory>
                            <overrideRootLogLevel>ERROR</overrideRootLogLevel>
                            <testResultsTimestamp>false</testResultsTimestamp>
                            <resultsFileFormat>xml</resultsFileFormat>
```

Is there anything we can add to the maven command or the maven config in pom.xml so that the jmx files run in parallel.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the maven multiple times. Each will execute a separate process.

Comment: Actually this is run from our regression test suite which is automated. Can you give example of running maven multiple times. How will that run separate jmx files in parallel?

Comment: maven program will basically initiate a process, you can call maven from multiple terminals, hence running multiple jmeter instances simultaneously. In your case, does regression test runner initiates  maven process. If that's the case, the above solution will not work.

Comment: Yes the regression test runner initiates the maven process, hence wanted something in the command or the config

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to fork the test execution. I never tried this for JMeter. Seems to be doable. Check the below link.

http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html